# How to change Typo3 Backend layout Name using TypoScript?

Tags: typo3

By default typo3 Back end layout give Normal,Left,Right and Border.

To hide the blocks i used following code

```
mod.SHARED.colPos_list = 0,1,2
```

How to rename the blocks in Typo script:

Normal - Description
Left- News
Right - Publications
Border - Footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using TYPO3 4.5+, you can use the new feature called backend layout or grid view.

It is very easy to use. You don't have to edit PHP-code. You just have to configure it using a wizard.

Joey Hasenau has written a good article at news.typo3.org about [how to use the backend layout](http://typo3.org/?id=181&tx_ttnews%5Btt_news%5D=956&L=&cHash=13178c3d21eef2ab2714421c9ce21085).

I hope, this facilitates your daily work!

Comment: looks like the link went dead :(

Answer (score 3):

When inserting the following in the **Page TSConfig** of the root page, the values of the dropdown "Columns" are changed when editing content elements:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.colPos.altLabels {
    0 = News
    1 = Description
    2 = Publications
    3 = Footer
}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, this is only halfway :(

---

According to [*Spalten ändern und umbenennen*](http://www.sk-typo3.de/Spalten-aendern-und-umbenennen.155.0.html) you'll need to edit `typo3conf/extTables.php` which affects all pages in the tree:

```
t3lib_extMgm::addPageTSConfig('  
    mod.SHARED.colPos_list = 0,1,2,3  
');  

$TCA["tt_content"]["columns"]["colPos"]["config"]["items"] = array (  
    "1" => array ("News||||||||||","1"),  
    "0" => array ("Description||||||||||","0"),  
    "3" => array ("Publications||||||||||","3"),  
    "2" => array ("Footer||||||||||","2"),  
);
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I tried Both solutions. Its not working.

Comment: @Sivakumar Updated - unfortunately I'm not able to solve this completely .(